# Magento2. How to create a column that will not be tied to the database

Tags: php, magento2

I have a table. And I want to create a column, which will be displayed simply HTML data for client. But how to do it, I do not know. I climbed the entire Internet and did not find the answer.

[xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIhPN.png)

[ebayInfo.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX3eW.png)

Comment: Please provide some example and data. How you are gonna populate the column which you are talking about?

Comment: a column where?

Comment: I did, but not sure if this is the right decision. I edited my question, please see.